# JavaScript, Iterate through object of arrays

Tags: javascript

I have an Object like this:

```
{
    1: [{'id':'1','value':'aa'}],
    2: [{'id':'2', 'value':'aa'}, {'id':'2','value':'bb'}],
    3: [{'id':'34', 'value':'cc'}]
}
```

[image]

How should I iterate that object? I'm very confused about it

I tried things like:

```
// object es my var 
Array.from(object).forEach(a => {
    console.log(a)
});

Array.prototype.forEach.call(object, child => {
    console.log(child)
});
```

With out success

Comment: Object.keys.forEach, Object.entries.forEach, etc. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just do a for in loop:

```js
for (var property in object) {
  //Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: This is an **often repeated** duplicate. It doesn't need an answer, just a close vote and (in some cases) a comment.